# How to convert Swift Date or String to timestamp without time zone of PostgreSQL?

Tags: swift, xcode, postgresql, vapor, postico

I am using Vapor 3, Swift 5.1, PostgreSQL 12, and Postico 1.5.10 for my Backend. In the PostgreSQL database, there is a field with the name `eventDate` of type `timestamp without time zone`.
Please, look at screenshot:

[image]

In Vapor, there is a model:

```
import Vapor
import FluentPostgreSQL

final class TestModel: PostgreSQLModel {

    var id: Int?
    var eventDate: Date

    init(eventDate: Date) {
        self.eventDate = eventDate
    }

}

extension TestModel: Content {
}

extension TestModel: Migration {
}

extension TestModel: Parameter {
}
```

But when I am trying to save `Date` (Swift) to `timestamp without time zone` Vapor gives me error:

```
[ ERROR ] DecodingError.typeMismatch: Value of type 'String' required for key 'eventDate.date'. (NIOServer.swift:104)
```

If, in model, I am changing `Date` to `String`, Vapor gives me this error:

```
[ ERROR ] PostgreSQLError.server.error.transformAssignedExpr: column "eventDate" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type text (NIOServer.swift:104)
```

So the question is: how to transfer `Date` and `String` to `timestamp without time zone` (or `timestamp with time zone`)?

I will be thankful for any help or advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's no 100% solution I wanted but it's also very good.

```
import Vapor
import FluentPostgreSQL

final class TestModel: PostgreSQLModel {

    static var createdAtKey: TimestampKey? = \.createdAt

    var id: Int?
    var someValue: Int
    var someOtherProprty: String
    var createdAt: Date?

    init(someValue: Int, someOtherProprty: String) {
        self.someValue = someValue
        self.someOtherProprty = someOtherProprty
    }

}

extension TestModel: Content {
}

extension TestModel: Migration {
}

extension TestModel: Parameter {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you save time stamps without a time zone? time stamp without a time zone is not a date - it is a string.

any way - you just have to init a time format without a time zone, then just use it to get a string.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
// initially set the format based on your datepicker date / server String
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

let myString = formatter.string(from: Date())
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for help, but this is not working. If I am trying to save String (like yours format) in without time zone, I get error: column "date" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type text

Comment: I am not using swift on server side - only client side. so i cannot give you a sample code - but i fond a link with explanation for you - and it tells you in more details what i told you just before. https://razvan.net/2017/02/23/swift-on-server-part-3/

Comment: Thank you for this site, but method, he is using, it does not work. He uses Vapor 2 and some Nodes. I think, he just transfer Date to String with some special rules, but it does not work. Now rules changed, I think.